# Group by STRING and sum another field as you group

Tags: android, sqlite

I just recently got a job maintaining an app that stores some products in a table. In the table there is the quantity of the product. There are a random number of records in the table so one product could have 1 to n records inside. Because I wasn't designing the app someone made the table this way, (If it was me, I'd create a new table just for products then group by id, would work great I presume, but I cant change it now.). Now I have a problem since I never did this before (Not on MSSQL and not on SQLite for that matter). How would you group by product name and sum the quantity of grouped items?

This doesn't work but probabbly I can be more clear what i want:

```
SELECT Name, Quantity
FROM products
GROUP BY Name
```

(there is SUM somewhere here, but if I put sum on quantity this will probabbly just return the sum of all quantities not just the ones grouped.

Another example (these are records in the table):

```
NAME     Quantity
ItemA    1
ItemA    7 
ItemB    8
ItemC    1
ItemB    2
```

The desired result of the query to fetch all elements but grouped would be:

```
ItemA  8
ItemB 10
ItemC  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `SUM` on the `Quantity`:

```
SELECT Name, Sum(Quantity) as Total
FROM products
GROUP BY Name
```

This will `SUM` the `Quantity` according to the unique `Name` groups :)