# Sum identical entries and corresponding integers from a different column

Tags: sqlite

Suppose I'm given a table of the following format named Store:

```
Product:    NumSold:

Mushroom    2
Ham         6
Apple       6
Mushroom    8
Ham         10
Apple       5
```

In plain language, I want to find the total number of each product sold.  In more technical terms, I want to take each unique entry in the "Product" column and sum up all of the matching entries in the "NumSold" column.  The desired result is as follows:

```
Mushroom     10
Ham          16
Apple        11
```

(In any order of course.)

I don't know if there's a technical term for this kind of summing so I've not been able to effectively Google for an answer.  But I tried a query like the following:

```
SELECT Product, SUM(NumSold) FROM Store;
```

And got:

```
Apple   37
```

Which isn't the desired result.  Is there any way to get my desired result in SQLite? (Keep in mind the tables I'm working with contain far more entries than this example.)  I'm hoping if there's any shortcut function I'm not aware of instead of having to use loops to accomplish this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
SELECT Product, SUM(NumSold) FROM Store GROUP BY Product;
```

Source: [Group by STRING and sum another field as you group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24177890/group-by-string-and-sum-another-field-as-you-group)